# Archive data under certain conditions

Tags: php, mysql, archive

I have two tables, `projects` and `archive` with identical columns. As you understand, I need to archive projects in the `archive` table, under certain conditions.

I wrote two requests, and they work fine if executed separately, but I'd like to assemble them.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO archive (idDocument,documentNumber,submissionDate,projectName)
        SELECT idDocument,documentNumber,submissionDate,projectName
        FROM projects
        WHERE id='".$id."'";

$sql = "DELETE FROM projects
        WHERE id='".$id."'";
```

1/ First of all, how can I assemble these two requests? I keep getting syntax errors.

2/ Now, I assign projects a status (in a column named `status`) from "1" to "3" in PHP and I'd like to archive these projects two months after they have reached status "3". How can I do so?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Did you place the ending delimiter `;` at the end of each request ? (When they are collapsed)

Comment: What do you mean by "assemble" the queries?  They are two distinct operations.  If you want to perform them atomically, you will need to execute them in a transaction (which requires support from the storage engine); are you using InnoDB?  For the second part of your question, I'd recommend recording in a column within the `projects` table the date on which the record moved to status '3'.

Comment: By "assembling" I meant executing the two requests in one single call, just as @shadyyx wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not know what You mean by assembling, maybe You want to query these two queries in just one simple call, then each query should be ended by query delimiter - a semicolon `;`, like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO archive (idDocument,documentNumber,submissionDate,projectName)
    SELECT idDocument,documentNumber,submissionDate,projectName
    FROM projects
    WHERE id='".$id."';

    DELETE FROM projects
    WHERE id='".$id."';";
```

If You want to archive+delete the projects with status 3 after two months they had been statused by 3, You will have to do these things:

1. when updating the project to status 3 also set the `date_changed = NOW()` (or similar expression)
2. write down a CRON job that will be executed let's say every day at 3:00 am.
3. the CRON job will call a PHP script that will walk down the `projects` table and archive + delete all the projects with status 3 where `date_changed` is less then or equal to `NOW() - INTERVAL '2' MONTHS`...

That should do the trick...

Comment: Excellent, thanks, I'll look into that. I still get the SQL syntax error though, any idea why?

Comment: I don't think so, both requests work if executed separately. The syntax error is at line 6 which is : `DELETE FROM projects`.

Comment: OK, then You will have to use `mysqli` and concretely the method `mysqli::multi_query` - http://php.net/mysqli_multi_query. If there is no space to use mysqli Or You do not want to rewrite all Your DB layer then there is no way to call two or more queries from PHP at once...

Comment: I am having trouble writing the cron job, it's the first time I do it and it's quite confusing. Where exactly do I have to put the condition (`date_changed` is less then or equal to `NOW() - INTERVAL '2' MONTHS`)?

Comment: In Your CRON job - that will be normal PHP script called by crontab program within Your UNIX server You will query the database to get all those records from the `projects` table and in this query in the `where` clause You will use the condition I gave You... `WHERE date_changed <= NOW() - INTERVAL '2' MONTHS'`. But this could be all about new question..

Comment: Ok I see, so I have to set a cron job that will run let's say once a week and that will call a PHP script in which I will set the SQL query. Is that right?